# Cann't get the latitude & longitude value.what should be change?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

[output screenshot with Toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Pzb.jpg)

// here the button on homeactivity.java

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gps = new GpsTracker(DrAppointHome.this);

                if(gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,update).commit();
                    update.update(latitude, longitude);

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Can't get location.
                    // GPS or network is not enabled.
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
```

// here the code of GpsTracker.java

```
public class GpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // Flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // Flag for network status
//    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // Flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // Location
    double latitude; // Latitude
    double longitude; // Longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GpsTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



            if (!isGPSEnabled) {
                // No network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("TD", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                Log.e("TD", "Lat: "+latitude);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        try {
            if (locationManager != null) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GpsTracker.this);
            }
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }


    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }



    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);


        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");


        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");


        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });


        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

// here the Request handlercode on java

```
public class RequestHandlerNearme {
    List<String> sb;
    List<DoctorNearMe> drList1 = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                        HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;



        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                sb  = new ArrayList<>();
                String response = "";

                }
                for (int i = 0; i<sb.size()-7; i=i+7){

                    drList1.add(new DoctorNearMe(sb.get(i),sb.get(i+1),sb.get(i+2),sb.get(i+3),sb.get(i+4),Double.parseDouble(sb.get(i+5)),Double.parseDouble(sb.get(i+6))));

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

// here the fragment code on java

```
public class DoctorNearYou extends Fragment {
    private static final String NEAR_YOU_URL = "http://doctorsportal.netne.net/nearme.php";
    private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";

    private List<String> result;
    ListView list;
    public RequestHandlerNearme rh = new RequestHandlerNearme();

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctornearyoufragment,null);
    }

    public void update(final double latitude, final double longitude) {
        rh.drList1.clear();

        class TDsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DoctorNearMe> {
            public TDsAdapter(){
                super(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_list_view_near_me,rh.drList1);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View itemView = convertView;
                if (itemView == null) {
                    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view_near_me, parent, false);
                }


                DoctorNearMe currentItem = rh.drList1.get(position);
                TextView dRName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dRName1);
                dRName.setText(currentItem.getDrName());

                TextView drSpeciality = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drSpeciality1);
                drSpeciality.setText(currentItem.getDrSpeciality());

                TextView drJobTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drJobTitle1);
                drJobTitle.setText(currentItem.getDrJobTitle());

                ImageView drProPic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drPropic1);
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(currentItem.getDrProPic()).into(drProPic);



                double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
                double dLat = Math.toRadians(currentItem.getlatitude()-latitude);
                double dLng = Math.toRadians(currentItem.getLongitude()-longitude);
                double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(currentItem.getlatitude())) *
                                Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
                double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
               Double Distence = (Double) ((earthRadius * c)/1000);




                TextView distence = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.drdistence);
                distence.setText(Distence+"");

                return itemView;
            }
        }


        class LoadDoctors extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<String> s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);


                s.remove(s.size() - 1);
                s.remove(s.size() - 1);
                s.remove(s.size() - 1);


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+s.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ArrayAdapter<DoctorNearMe> adapter = new TDsAdapter();

                list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drlistforhome1);

                list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();

                param.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude+"");
                param.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude+"");
                result = rh.sendPostRequest(NEAR_YOU_URL, param);

                return result;
            }
        }

        new LoadDoctors().execute();



    }


}
```

// here the code of

```
public class DoctorNearMe {
    public String drName;
    public String drSpeciality;
    public String drJobTitle;
    public String drProPic;
    public String drUname;
    public Double latitude;
    public Double longitude;
    public DoctorNearMe(String drName, String drSpeciality, String drJobTitle, String drProPic, String drUname, Double latitude, Double longitude) {
        this.drName = drName;
        this.drSpeciality = drSpeciality;
        this.drJobTitle = drJobTitle;
        this.drProPic = drProPic;
        this.drUname = drUname;
        this.latitude= latitude;
        this.longitude=longitude;
    }

    public String getDrName() {
        return drName;
    }

    public void setDrName(String drName) {
        this.drName = drName;
    }

    public String getDrSpeciality() {
        return drSpeciality;
    }

    public void setDrSpeciality(String drSpeciality) {
        this.drSpeciality = drSpeciality;
    }

    public String getDrJobTitle() {
        return drJobTitle;
    }

    public void setDrJobTitle(String drJobTitle) {
        this.drJobTitle = drJobTitle;
    }

    public String getDrProPic() {
        return drProPic;
    }

    public void setDrProPic(String drProPic) {
        this.drProPic = drProPic;
    }

    public String getDrUname() {
        return drUname;
    }

    public void setDrUname(String drUname) {
        this.drUname = drUname;
    }

    public Double getlatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude= latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude= longitude;
    }

}
```

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!isGPSEnabled) {
    // No network provider is enabled
} else { .... }
```

**First thing**, you are using just only gps provider to get locations, if GPS is not enabled, your code goes out of scope and never make location request. Be aware this situation of your code.

**Secondly,** when you call getLocation() method, it can't get new location asap maybe you know. Then, you get only cached location of gps provider. If it has no cached location data, your method will return null and location parameter will be null until the gps provider got new location

I see a few thing, whenever you click the fab button it creates GpsTracker, so what about previously requested location updates ?

And why dont you set the location parameter below ?

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}
....
double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
```

If you dont, getLatitude and getLongitude return cached values or null (referring to my Secondly section)